# I am not able to get a field in my Django ManyToMany Relation

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I have a model called announcement in my Django Models, the way it works is that it has a message field which I can type the body of the message as well as the student_id which is the receiver of the message. I am using the many-to-many field on the student_id so that I am able to send the message to either some particular student and then filter the particular student message in on their frontend, but when I am trying the filter the particular student which I selected when sending the message, it doesn't display any information at all.

[image: The space keeps being blank despite the fact that I have selected some particular student for the message]

models.py

```
class Announcement_by_dean(models.Model):
    student_id = models.ManyToManyField(add_students_by_manager)
    message = models.TextField()
    sent_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now(), blank=True)
    updated_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "message sent on "+ str(self.sent_date)

class add_students_by_manager(models.Model):
    manager_ID = models.ForeignKey(Manager_login_information, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_ID = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    major = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student_name
```

views.py

```
def dean_page(request):
    annoucement_list = Announcement_by_dean.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    return render(request, 'dean_page.html', context)
```

dean_page.html

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show" id="nav-announcement-list" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-announcement-list-tab">
  {% if annoucement_list %}
  {% for k in annoucement_list %}
  <div class="card container mt-4 mb-5">
    <div class="card-body">
      Messsage: {{k.message}}<br>
      Sent to: {{k.student_id.student_ID}}<br>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
  <div class="mt-4 ml-5 pl-5">
    <span class="text-muted container pt-5 pl-5 ml-5">No Annoucement(s) has been made</span>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over student_id as it is a many to many field.

```
{% for student in k.student_id.all %}
    {{ student.student_ID }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If I want something similar in the Django admin as well. how can I modify the "    def __str__(self):
        return "message sent on "+ str(self.sent_date)" + " to " + str(self.student_id.student_ID) to get something similar.

Comment: @coderboy you need to loop over `self.student_id.all()`. something like `', '.join([i.student_ID for i in self.student_id.all()])` would give you a comma separated string.